# join two tables that have keys that references the same key on a third table without using the third table

Tags: mysql

I have a table named A that has a foreign key named id that references id on table B
I also have a table named C that has a foreign key that references id on table B.
I want to join table A and C and use only the common data of A and C and I don't care if B has extra data

Can I use this :

`A inner join C on a.id=c.id`

Or I must use this :

`A inner join B on a.id=b.id inner join C on b.id=c.id`

The only reason I ask is because i read that I must use joins on foreign keys because it is safer but if I can use only 1 join istead of 2 then why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An RDBMS like MySQL will let you join *any* set of columns to any compatible (same number and types) set of columns in any other table, so yes, your first query will work.  But it will be slow if MySQL can't find an index to use.  (When joining to some table's PK column, there is always an index to use, so these joins are always (relatively) quick.)

If neither table has an index on its `id` field, then MySQL will need to do a nested loop join, which is likely to be slow unless one of the tables is very small -- it can take time proportional to the product of the table sizes.  To give the MySQL query planner the best chance at using an index, make sure that at least one of `a` or `b` has an index on its `id` field (or, more generally, has an index on multiple fields, the *first* of which is `id`).  Usually it makes the most sense to put the index on the larger table, and loop through each row of the smaller table, looking up items in the other table using its index -- but what strategy the query planner actually chooses is ultimately up to its own estimates of how efficient the various different possible plans are.

Use EXPLAIN to check that it really is using your index.